# Duvida typedef void*

Tags: c

Galera estou vendo a sequinte expresão:

```
typedef void* type_t;
```

então estava fazendo uns testes e coloquei `type_t` em um `sizeof` e ele me retornou 4 bytes de tamanho mais como assim ?

Answer (score 7):

`void *` é um ponteiro para um endereço arbitrário de memória, e não um ponteiro para "nada". O fato de ter retornado `4` na sua implementação quer dizer que você está com uma aplicação de 32 bits (onde os endereços de memória são representados em 4 bytes). Se você compilar o mesmo código em uma aplicação de 64 bits (ou algum outro valor), o resultado do `sizeof` será diferente.